# Server attack, how to fix it

Tags: ubuntu

Looks like the server is attacked. Contents of /var/log/auth.log are as follows. Its trying to ssh with all these username, how can I shut it off. The server is Ubuntu.

```
    Feb 22 16:29:15 server sshd[23413]: Failed password for invalid user mirror from 220.132.192.220 port 43881 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:15 server sshd[23414]: Failed password for invalid user justice from 220.132.192.220 port 43882 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:15 server sshd[23416]: Failed password for invalid user london from 220.132.192.220 port 43885 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:15 server sshd[23415]: Failed password for invalid user justice from 220.132.192.220 port 43884 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23421]: Invalid user oxford from 203.66.115.43
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23421]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23421]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=203.66.115.43 
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23422]: Invalid user london from 203.66.115.43
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23422]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23422]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=203.66.115.43 
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23424]: Invalid user london from 203.66.115.43
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23424]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23424]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=203.66.115.43 
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23423]: Invalid user mirror from 203.66.115.43
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23423]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:17 server sshd[23423]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=203.66.115.43 
Feb 22 16:29:19 server sshd[23421]: Failed password for invalid user oxford from 203.66.115.43 port 43959 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:19 server sshd[23422]: Failed password for invalid user london from 203.66.115.43 port 43962 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:19 server sshd[23424]: Failed password for invalid user london from 203.66.115.43 port 43967 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:19 server sshd[23423]: Failed password for invalid user mirror from 203.66.115.43 port 43964 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:20 server sshd[23429]: Invalid user pacific from 220.132.192.220
Feb 22 16:29:20 server sshd[23429]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23429]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=220.132.192.220 
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23430]: Invalid user mirror from 220.132.192.220
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23430]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23430]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=220.132.192.220 
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23432]: Invalid user oxford from 220.132.192.220
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23431]: Invalid user mirror from 220.132.192.220
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23432]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23432]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=220.132.192.220 
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23431]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:21 server sshd[23431]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=220.132.192.220 
Feb 22 16:29:22 server sshd[23429]: Failed password for invalid user pacific from 220.132.192.220 port 44073 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:22 server sshd[23430]: Failed password for invalid user mirror from 220.132.192.220 port 44078 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:23 server sshd[23432]: Failed password for invalid user oxford from 220.132.192.220 port 44082 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:23 server sshd[23431]: Failed password for invalid user mirror from 220.132.192.220 port 44079 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23437]: Invalid user pizza from 202.39.75.16
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23437]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23437]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=202.39.75.16 
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23438]: Invalid user oxford from 202.39.75.16
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23438]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23438]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=202.39.75.16 
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23441]: Invalid user oxford from 202.39.75.16
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23441]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23441]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=202.39.75.16 
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23440]: Invalid user pacific from 202.39.75.16
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23440]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:24 server sshd[23440]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=202.39.75.16 
Feb 22 16:29:26 server sshd[23437]: Failed password for invalid user pizza from 202.39.75.16 port 44173 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:27 server sshd[23438]: Failed password for invalid user oxford from 202.39.75.16 port 44184 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:27 server sshd[23441]: Failed password for invalid user oxford from 202.39.75.16 port 44186 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:27 server sshd[23440]: Failed password for invalid user pacific from 202.39.75.16 port 44185 ssh2
Feb 22 16:29:28 server sshd[23445]: Invalid user quality from 220.132.192.198
Feb 22 16:29:28 server sshd[23445]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:28 server sshd[23445]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=220.132.192.198 
Feb 22 16:29:29 server sshd[23446]: Invalid user pacific from 220.132.192.198
Feb 22 16:29:29 server sshd[23446]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:29 server sshd[23446]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=220.132.192.198 
Feb 22 16:29:29 server sshd[23448]: Invalid user pacific from 220.132.192.198
Feb 22 16:29:29 server sshd[23448]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Feb 22 16:29:29 server sshd[23448]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=220.132.192.198 
Feb 22 16:29:29 server sshd[23450]: Invalid user pizza from 220.132.192.198
Feb 22 16:29:29 server sshd[23450]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
```

Answer (score 8):

Been brought up a few times I believe:

[Securing SSH on Linux Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/93430/securing-ssh-on-linux-ubuntu)

[Hundreds of failed ssh logins](https://serverfault.com/questions/17870/hundreds-of-failed-ssh-logins)

BTW these attempts are VERY common, usually automated scripts.

Answer (score 8):

Install `denyhosts`.

`apt-get install denyhosts`

Deny hosts is a daemon that watches your servers logs, generally `/var/log/secure`, for *suspicious* access patterns and if found, adds the IP addresses of curious visitors to `/etc/hosts.deny` causing `sshd` to block them outright.

It also has a mode that allows it to exchange the local block list with lists from other machines, in a way, crowdsourcing known bad IP addresses. Similar to the way RBL lists work for SMTP.

I would also recommend you disable `keyboard-interactive` authentication on your ssh daemon to prevent someone accidentally creating a test user account, with an easy to guess password.

Comment: fail2ban is another option

Comment: I used to use fail2ban, but I liked deny hosts because it wasn't reliant on using iptables.

Comment: Yep, denyhosts is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

- Change SSH to a different port
- Block the IP addresses for a short time and they might give up